# How to trigger an error/warning immediately upon compile/run if an item on my class-path is missing

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath, compiler-warnings, javac

I have a very simple source file -- `HelloWorld.java`

```java
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

I have the following compile command.

`javac HelloWorld.java`

If I run it, this works fine.

I have the following run command.

`java HelloWorld`

If I run it, this works fine too.

---

Now, I also have a single jar file (`some.jar`) as a dependency. I am not using it yet, but I will be, and therefore, want to start putting it onto my class-path.

So, I tried to run the above 2 commands with a `--class-path` included this time.

`javac --class-path=".;some.jar" HelloWorld.java`

`java --class-path=".;some.jar" HelloWorld`

This also worked.

Finally, I accidentally deleted my `some.jar`, and reran the above 2 commands.

Surprisingly enough, there were no errors or warnings from Java.

My question is -- how do I get Java to tell me that it cannot find the item I have listed on my classpath? I don't really care if the warning is upon compile or upon run, but I would like to know I made a mistake some point before my program actually tries to use the dependency (and fail because Java couldn't find it this entire time).

Basically, I want some form of confirmation or reaffirmation that Java knows where my specified items on the class-path are, and can reach them.

***Please recall, this is a minimal, reproducible example. My actual problem involves WAY more moving pieces. I'm using this (admittedly contrived) example as a way to highlight my point.***

===

**EDIT** - To better explain why this is a problem, let's leave the minimal example and talk about my actual problem. I am in the middle of overhauling my codebase. I am trying to update dependencies, refactor code, reorganize my folder structure, and more. In the midst of this, I run into a ClassNotFoundException. The first time, it was because I had an out-of-date version of my dependency. But the second time, it was because I had put the jar file in the wrong location, and more specifically, the location that I had put on the class-path was pointing at a non-existent jar file location.

I want to nip this problem in the bud by having Java tell me upfront if the class-path location I am providing it is pointing to nothing at all. Not being able to do that hurts the maintainability of my codebase significantly during large refactors and overhauls.

**EDIT 2** - If there is no other option besides using a build tool (Maven/Gradle/etc), then I am willing to consider that. But I want to emphasize, that is a worst-case scenario solution. My project is suffering from enough complexity as is, and the last thing I want to do is uproot by build solution from the ground up.

My goal is to make small, incremental changes all over my code base. All together, it adds up to a complete overhaul, but it's made up of a bunch of tiny, bite-sized steps. Layering on an entire build system to my codebase is the exact opposite of small and bite-sized. My original build solution works great, it just ran into this problem while refactoring.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. If the program works in both cases, this is indicative that the external `.jar` is not used. Java cannot possibly know that you intend to use that `.jar` in the future. If you actually *use* the `.jar` and it is not present, then you will get a compilation- or runtime error, depending on how you use the external `.jar`.

Comment: @Turing85 I have added an edit that includes some more context.

Comment: I recommend using a build tool like [`gradle` (`gradle.org`)](https://gradle.org/) or [`maven` (`maven.apache.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage your dependencies. You may want to look at subprojects / multi-module builds.

Comment: @Turing85 That would just end up with me routing my dependencies through Maven/Gradle to Java vs just straight to Java. I am very familiar with Maven, but at the moment, it would add a lot more complexity/brittleness to my problem with little of the benefit. If there is no other way to achieve what I am asking for, then I am willing to consider that as an answer to my question. But it certainly is not a good fit for my problem at all.

Comment: Is adding code to your program that checks the classpath entries explicitly a suitable option for you?

Comment: @TimMoore Better than a build tool! edit - well, maybe, I don't know exactly what you have in mind

Comment: Please, consider review [this article](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue037-Checking-That-Your-Classpath-Is-Valid.html) from the Java Specialists blog, it is quite dated but I hope it may be of help.

Comment: @jccampanero WOW, this is almost exactly what I was looking for. Put that into an answer and I will award the bounty to you. What a smart idea. Java is such a flexible language.

Comment: Thank you very much @davidalayachew, I really appreciate it, although all the credit goes to the [Java Specialist blog](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/) people. I am happy to hear that the comment was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the question comment, sometime ago I came across [a Java Specialists blog](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/) [article](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue037-Checking-That-Your-Classpath-Is-Valid.html) that could still be of help.

Basically, it defines a helper class `ClassPathInfo` like the following one:

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClassPathInfo {
  private final ClassLoader classLoader;

  public ClassPathInfo(ClassLoader classLoader) {
    this.classLoader = classLoader;
  }

  public ClassPathInfo() {
    this(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
  }

  /**
   * validates classpath, throws an LinkageError if invalid
   * classpath was specified
   */
  public void validateClassPath() {
    try {
      URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)classLoader).getURLs();
      for(int i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        try {
          urls[i].openStream();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
          throw new LinkageError(
            "malformed class path url:\n "+urls[i]);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
          throw new LinkageError(
            "invalid class path url:\n "+urls[i]);
        }
      }
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "The current VM's System classloader is not a "
        + "subclass of java.net.URLClassLoader");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathInfo info = new ClassPathInfo();
    info.validateClassPath();
  }
}
```

This class uses the system class loader, which turns out to be an instance of `URLClassLoader`, to check the existence of every entry found in the class path.

The blog includes a helper script for simplifying the invocation of `ClassPathInfo` named `checkcp.bat`:

```
@echo off 
rem Set STRICTHOME to the directory you're deploying this file to.
set STRICTHOME=C:\strictjava

if ""=="%3" (
  set STRICTCP="%CLASSPATH%;%STRICTHOME%"
) else (
  if -classpath==%1 (
    set STRICTCP="%2;%STRICTHOME%"
  )else (
    echo If more than three parameters are specified,
    echo the first has to be -classpath.
    set ERRORLEVEL=1
    goto end
  )
)

java -classpath %STRICTCP% ClassPathInfo
set STRICTHOME=
set STRICTCP=

:end
```

This script basically tries to set the value of the `STRICTCP` variable by analyzing the arguments provided to the `bat` script file. This variable will be the one actually used for checking the classpath when invoking `ClassPathInfo`.

The article include a couple of helper scripts for both `javac`:

```
@echo off
call checkcp %1 %2 %3
if not %errorlevel%==0 goto END
javac %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
:END
```

and `java` commands invocations:

```
@echo off
call checkcp %1 %2 %3
if not %errorlevel%==0 goto END
java %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
:END
```

To understand `checkcp.bat` let's review the example provided in the site, based on the invocation of `strictjava`:

```
strictjava -classpath "c:\sub\jar1.jar;c:\sub2\jar2.jar" MyClass
```

As indicated in the helper `bat` files:

```
call checkcp %1 %2 %3
```

we are passing here three arguments to `checkcp`, in order:

```
%1=-classpath
%2=c:\sub\jar1.jar;c:\sub2\jar2.jar
%3=MyClass
```

It means that, according to this instruction in `checkcp.bat`:

```
set STRICTCP="%2;%STRICTHOME%"
```

the effective class path that will be checked is the following one:

```
STRICTCP="c:\sub\jar1.jar;c:\sub2\jar2.jar;C:\strictjava"
```

If in contrast, you use something like this:

```
strictjava MyClass
```

`checkcp` will try to analyze the environment variable `CLASSPATH` for checking the class path, as indicated in this code fragment:

```
if ""=="%3" (
  set STRICTCP="%CLASSPATH%;%STRICTHOME%"
)
```

Note that according to the script the `-classpath` flag should be the first one provided.

Please, take the script only as a reference of the actual implementation, adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to accept this answer, but could you expand on the batch and helper scripts? I don't understand them at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @davidalayachew. Of course. I updated the answer with further explanations. Please, don't hesitate to tell me if you need further details, I will be glad to help if possible.

Comment: Bounty awarded, this is exactly the answer I was looking for when I asked this question. I just never knew that it was possible with naked Java. Excellent, ty vm! EDIT - actually going to award an extra bounty because this answer is so exemplary. For those reading in, feel free to answer, but know that the 300 point bounty is going to this poster. If you come with something better, I will hand out a separate bounty to you too.

Comment: I am at a loss for words @davidalayachew... The new bounty was absolutely unnecessary... I honestly don't know what to say... Thank you, thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Anytime, np at all